# AuthComponent works great in development mode, but not in production?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm getting a bizarre error when using CakePHP's AuthComponent. As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with the code itself. It's working great on my development machine and the production server. However, if I change the 'debug' level in app/Core/config.php from 2 (development) to 0 (production) on the production server, the app fails with nothing but this in the error logs:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AuthComponent' not found in /path/to/my/app/View/Elements/auth_status.ctp on line 3

I've checked that the file is present in `lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php`. I've also experimentally added/removed `App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component')` to AppController and my individual controllers to no avail. This one has me stumped, and I can't reproduce the error on my development machine. This seems to indicate a server issue, but I'm at a loss to find an explanation, and the docs aren't clear on the prerequisites required to run the AuthComponent. Any ideas how I can fix it? Thanks!

For reference, here's my AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
  public $helpers = array('Recaptcha.Recaptcha');
  public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
  );

  public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow();
  }
}
```

The code for auth_status.ctp:

```
        <div class="pull-right">
        <?php if (AuthComponent::user('id')): ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link("Welcome!", '/users/view/'.AuthComponent::user('id'));?>
             | 
            <?php echo $this->Html->link('Logout', '/users/logout');?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link('Login', '/users/login');?>
             | 
            <?php echo $this->Html->link('Register', '/users/register');?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: what is your code in your element?

Comment: I've edited my question with the code, cheers

Comment: the app uses statement itself above your appcontroller file OR the $components declaration you got both should suffice. that's quite weird. is it an error page you are on? or a normal 200 page?

Comment: This probably isn't the answer to your problem but you don't need `parent::beforeFilter();` in your appController since it is the parent.

Comment: It was a normal 200 page, but it presented as broken HTML - the layout rendered everything up until the AuthComponent::user() line and just died. 

The plot thickens - setting it **back** to production mode eliminates the problem. I wonder how long that will last.

Comment: Not the answer, but thanks for the tip @TimJoyce

Comment: Where you able to solve this problem? I am stuck with the same error now. Can't understand what the difference between my laptop and the production server is that will cause this (and NOT complain about other include files missing).

Comment: Try to clear your app/tmp folder and rebuild the cache. I found that the problem disappeared if I didn't copy the contents of that folder at all when I deployed, and just rebuilt the folder structure after doing the transfer. Toggling between debug and production modes also seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this one. In core.php, there's a variable named $prefix that's used by the cache engine. If that engine is Memcache or APC, it must be changed to avoid naming collisions with any other Cake apps running on the server. My development laptop was using File cache engine, while the production server was using APC (and later Memcached). An older version of the same Cake app was running on that server and was *not* using AuthComponent. As soon as someone would make a request on that app, the other app would use the wrong cache and throw HTTP500 errors until I cleared the cache.

Change the $prefix variable to something unique to your app, and the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have different `php.ini` settings regarding [`include_path`](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

Check on development and on production server:

```
echo ini_get('include_path');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be related to [this issue](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2682-misleading-errors-when-some-exceptions-are-rendered-repeated-errors). The error in my code was totally unrelated to AuthComponent (or Cake at all).

Unfortunately I can't know what the error is in your case - I had to to some real debugging before I pin-pointed my error.

If anyone wonders; my error was that I accessed functions as arrays and my production server was running a PHP version < 5.4.

Comment: I still haven't confirmed a solution, but [toggling between debug and production mode a few times seems to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192361/authcomponent-works-great-in-development-mode-but-not-in-production/14553833?iemail=1#comment19679432_14192361). That suggested an issue with the app/tmp/cache folders, so I've made sure that those folders are not copied when I deploy to the production server.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem and as it turned out my problem was, that I tried to load a plugin in bootstrap.php, but didn't have it installed